# Mapping with infinite values - Winding number and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Is there a continuous closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with the property that the mapping
$$
\nu_{\gamma}: \mathbb{C} \backslash \operatorname{im}(\gamma) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
$$
takes infinitely many values? Note that im is here the image, not the imaginary part and that $\nu_{\gamma}$ denotes the winding number
$$
\nu_{\gamma}=\text{wind}_\gamma.
$$

---

The closed curves, which one usually encounters in
complex analysis do not seem to have this property.

Comment: By "infinite values" do you mean "infinitely many values"? See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Hawaiian_Earrings.svg/250px-Hawaiian_Earrings.svg.png

Comment: Take an analytic function in the unit disc with $f(0)=0$ and infinitely many zeroes on the segment $[0,1)$ (by necessity accumulating at $1$) and which is continuous radially at $1$ and take $\gamma=f([0,1])$ continuous and closed; if $r_n$ are the increasing zeroes on $[0,1)$, then $f([r_{n-1}, r_n])$ is also closed and points "inside" it but "outside" $f([r_n,1])$ should have a winding number around $n$ - this, of course, is not rigorous but using something like $(z-1)B(z)$ where $B$ is the infinite Blaschke product with zeroes at $1-1/n^2, n \ge 1$ may be able to be explicitly shown

Comment: Geometrically $\gamma$ should look like an infinite sequence of "circles" inner tangent at $0$  with radiuses $r_n \to 0$ and one contained in the next, and then the points in-between the $n$, $n+1$ circles have winding number around $n$